# How to rename multiple files with similar strings separated by periods and underscores with the rename command

Tags: bash, sed, rename

Ubuntu 16.04
Bash 4.4.20
Rename 0.20

I have hundreds of files that get copied to a folder each day. The folder name is different each day so the files on the inside of the folder have to be renamed

Here is an example of the files after being copied to the folder.

```
2019-11-30_hs5_felix.doggie.com_1112.garage
2019-12-01_hs5_ralph.doggie.com_1112.garage
2019-12-04_hs5_sartah.doggie.com_1112.garage
2019-12-05_hs5_felix.doggie.com_1112.garage
2019-12-07_hs5_ggg.doggie.com_1112.garage
2019-12-12_hs5_fex.doggie.com_1112.garage
2019-12-19_hs5_sioia.doggie.com_9999.garage
2019-12-21_hs5_felix.doggie.com_1002.garage
2019-12-22_hs5_sonia.doggie.com_1112.garage
2019-12-25_hs5_isabel.doggie.com_1106.garage
```

Here is the pattern that will be the same:

```
same_same_"${one}".same.same_"${two}".same
```

So the variables will represent two words we will use to rename all the files to and the files need to look like the following after being renamed:

```
one="ssss"
two="1234"

2019-11-30_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-01_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-04_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-05_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-07_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-12_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-19_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-21_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-22_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
2019-12-25_hs5_sssss.doggie.com_1234.garage
```

The final product is more important than how it is done so we can use any commands to get there.

Comment: The Ubuntu version and Bash version are nice, but do not tell us a thing about the `rename` command you have on your system. There are two separate Linux `rename` commands that function very very differently. One is from the `util-linux` package (does not support regular expression matching) and `perl-rename` that does. Show the output of `rename --version`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Rename version 0.20. I'm looking at your answer. All of the explanation you did is why I come back to this website each day.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions and I'm happy to explain further. I looked at using `rename`, but with the util-linux version, you are limited to replacing the first occurrence of an expression. In your case you need to replace two expressions. Which means perl-rename would be the only choice -- but then you are limited to requiring that package -- which many distributions don't include. You will generally find `sed` on all. You can also do the replacement in parts using just bash *parameter expansions* -- which is another good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without rename, you can actually change the names of the files making both substitutions of `"$one"` and `"$two"` using the `mv` command and a *command-substitution* using `sed`. This eliminates the *"Which version of rename do I have?"*

For example, in your case, you can change to the directory containing the files, and do:

```
one="ssss"
two="1234"

for i in *; do 
    mv "$i" "$(sed 's/^\(.*hs5_\)[^.]*\([.].*com_\)[0-9]*\(.*$\)/\1'"$one"'\2'"$two"'\3/' <<< "$i")"
done
```

Which makes use of `sed` normal substitution command making use of three-capture groups and backreferences.

**Explanation**

The `sed` substitution command is `sed 's/find/replace/'` where in your case the find is broken into the parts:

- `^\(.*hs5_\)` match from the beginning of the filename through `"hs5_"` capturing the text within a capture group of `\( ... \)` using basic regular expressions to be reinserted with the first backreference `\1`;
- from `"hs5_"` on we match `[^.]*` a sequence of characters not containing a `'.'`;
- we then capture from the `'.'` through `"com_"` capturing `\([.].*com_\)` to reinsert with the second backreference `\2`; and finally
- capture all characters to the end of the filename with `\(.*$\)` for reinsertion as `\3`

For the replace portion, we just include the captured text making the variable substitutions:

- `\1'"$one"'\2'"$two"'\3`

(**note:** the quoting is very specific. The parts of the `sed` command are enclosed in single quotes which the shell variables are enclosed in double quotes, along with the complete command substitution.

The basic move of the file in accomplished with `mv "$i" "$(sed ... <<< "$i")` where the filename is fed to the `sed` command using a bash-only *Here-String* `<<<` which redirects the contents of the variable to the `sed` command on `stdin` allowing `sed` to make the substitutions completing the move.

Answer (score 2):

According to the pattern `same_same_"${one}".same.same_"${two}".same`, how about:

```
one="ssss"
two="1234"
for f in *.*; do
    IFS=_ read -ra a <<< "$f"
    a[2]="${one}.${a[2]#*.}"
    a[3]="${two}.${a[3]#*.}"
    (IFS=_; mv -- "$f" "${a[*]}")
done
```

It first splits the filename on `_`, replaces the specified positions with
the variables, then merges them again as a new filename.

Answer (score 2):

This also may work for you - (GNU parallel):

```
parallel 'mv {1} {=1 s/(_.*_)[^.]+(.*_)[^.]+/$1$arg[2]$2$arg[3]/ =}' ::: * ::: ssss ::: 1234
```

Use GNU parallel to eliminate forloop and shell variables. The `{=n ... =}` allows the use of perl commands on the n'th positional replacement string. In this case, use the substitution command to replace parts of each file name garnered from `::: *`.

**Note**: Before executing this command, it is always good practice to insert the `--dry-run` option and inspect its output before running it live.

Comment: Your example is well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i came out with this for your filenames(2019-12-19_hs5_sioia.doggie.com_9999.garage)

```
one="ssss"
two="1234"

for file in *; { name=${file//_[0-9]*.g/_$two.g}; name=${name//_*.d/_$one.d}; mv $file $name; }
```

This method uses variable substitutions ${var//pattern/change}